# Can't seem to catch error when using Jasmine toThrowError

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I beginning to try jasmine and I want to use the toThrowError() function but my test does not want to succeed.

I have one function where I throw an error:

**test.service.ts**

```
test(list:{}){ 
    if(list == null){
        throw new TypeError();
    }
    else{
        // do something...
    }
}
```

And my test :

```
it('shall throw an error', inject()
    [
        TestService
    ],
    (
        testService: TestService
    ) => {
        let test = testService.test(null);
        expect(test).toThrowError(TypeError);
    }
);
```

And my test fails with an Uncaught TypeError (when I call it I'm doing it in a try catch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should expect a function, that calls your function with `null`, to throw an error. Right now you're expecting the result of calling the function to throw an error, which isn't happening.

```
expect(() => testService.test(null)).toThrowError(TypeError);
```

---

Put another way, the following line in the test:

```
let test = testService.test(null);
```

executes the `test` function with `null`, throwing the `TypeError`. Because it's not within the `expect`, it is considered by jasmine to be "uncaught". After the error is thrown, nothing else is executed. The `expect(test).toThrowError(TypeError);` line is never called.

The code I've shown above passes a *function* to `expect`. When jasmine runs that function, it will throw the `TypeError`, and fulfill the `toThrowError(TypeError)` condition.

Comment: Can you please explain more? I didn't get the explanation?

Comment: Yes, I've finally understood it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- You might have to throw the error from the spy like this [here](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.throwError%3C/code%3E).
- You were expecting even before throwing the error

  ```
  spyOn(foo, "setBar").and.throwError("quux");
  ```